# Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile as array Laravel 4.2 file upload

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload loads of files simultaneously using `Laravel 4.2`, but it doesn't work.

When I try to upload 2 or more files, laravel uploads only the latest selected file.

Now I changed something and it gives me the error `Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile as array`.

Why does it return this error? And why doesn't he upload all the images?

My controller:

```
public function postUpload() {
  // getting all of the post data
  $files = Input::file('file');
  //echo "<pre>";
  //var_dump($files);
  //echo "</pre>";
  //die;
  $map = Input::get('mapname');
  // setting up rules
  $rules = array('file' => 'max:10000'); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
  // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
  $validator = Validator::make($files, $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    // send back to the page with the input data and errors
    Session::flash('error_message', 'Er ging iets mis!');
    return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
  }
  else {
    // checking file is valid.

        if($files)
        {
            //echo "<pre>";
            //var_dump(Input::hasFile('file'));
            //echo "</pre>";
            //die;
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                $destinationPath = 'public/pictures/overall/'.$map.'/'; // upload path
                $filename = str_random(40).'_'.$file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $file[0]->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
                $file[0]->move($destinationPath, $filename); // uploading file to given path
            }
        // sending back with message
        Session::flash('success', 'Succesvol geüpload!'); 
        return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload');
        }

    else {
      // sending back with error message.
      Session::flash('error_message', 'Er ging iets mis!');
      return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload');
    }
  }
}
```

The view I use:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminPictureController@PostUpload', 'accept-charset' => 'UTF-8', 'files' => true)) }}
<select id="mapname" name="mapname">
@foreach (array_reverse($folders) as $folder)
<option value="{{ $folder }}">{{ str_replace('-', ' ', $folder) }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<br><br>
{{ Form::file('file[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Uploaden</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The view rendered:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/RPR/admin/img/uploadfile" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="SkMoFqiOYBJZOOrvcwtMUGGjHV6gPftAq2mPE6Uz">
<select id="mapname" name="mapname">
<option value="TAC-Tielt-Shakedown-2015">TAC Tielt Shakedown 2015</option>
<option value="TAC-Tielt-2013">TAC Tielt 2013</option>
<option value="Rally-van-Staden-2015">Rally van Staden 2015</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input multiple="1" name="file[]" type="file">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Uploaden</button>
</form>
```

I get the error when I press `Uploaden` (the submit button).
When I press the button it goes to the route `Route::post('img/uploadfile', 'AdminPictureController@PostUpload');`

So he takes the controller. But where it goes wrong, I don't know. He highlights this: http://prntscr.com/892dbt

Hope someone know the answer.

Kindest regards,

Robin

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing the `$files = Input::file()`?

Comment: Yes, doing `var_dump($files);` gives me this: http://laravel.io/bin/DemDn (I tried to upload 3 files)

Comment: I see, I didn't expect that... :)

Comment: Yeah... I know. Everything is right for as far as I know. So I don't see why it just won't work... Do you have any idea? Or a working solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hm, let me see if I've got this right.

```
// Should be array of "UploadedFile" objects
$files = Input::file('file');

if($files)
{
    // Iterating over the array
    // "file" should be an instance of UploadedFile
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        // ** You cannot use $file[0] **
        $filename = str_random(40).'_'.$file[0]->getClientOriginalName();

        // Instead, use this
        $filename = str_random(40).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

    }
}
```

As you see above, `$file[0]` is the definitive reason for `Cannot use object of type UploadedFile as array` error.

This still does not solve the issue of a single file being shown instead of multiple. Are you sure that is still an issue here?

Comment: I found the solution thanks to you!  Approved the answer. Thanks!